# Java Changing Linux File Permission Sometimes Does not Work

Tags: java, linux

I am working on a task, which is changing the file's permission to 640 after our code exports the file to our Linux server. The same code works in our Dev server, but in our Uat server, sometimes the permission is changed to 640 successfully, sometimes the permission can not be changed, is still the default 600.

I checked the SystemOut.log, no any error for this.

My related Java code is like below:

```
private void exportXXXFiles() {
......
//Settings for the access permissions of the exported files
Set<PosixFilePermission> filePerms = new HashSet<PosixFilePermission>();
filePerms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_READ);
filePerms.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
filePerms.add(PosixFilePermission.GROUP_READ);
try {
            Path localFilePath = ......;            
            Files.setPosixFilePermissions(localFilePath, filePerms);
            ......            
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 }
```

I am confused why the same code works in our Dev server but not stable in our Uat server, where sometimes it works sometimes it does not work. I assume that is the environment issue, but I have no idea what the exact issue is. Who can give me some suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you get an exception when it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few reason why changing permissions might not work.  These include:

- The application doesn't have permission to change permissions.  With classic UNIX / Linux, you need to be the file owner or root to change an file's permissions.  Then there are ACLs.
- The file system might be read-only, or mounted read only.
- The file system type might not support the combination of permissions you are trying to use.  For example, FAT did not support execute permissions, and NTFS permissions work a bit differently.  Unfortunately, when you mount a "foreign" file system type on Linux, the OS doesn't provide a way to direcrly manipulate the file system's native permissions.
- It is possible that what you are trying to do is blocked by SE Linux or AppArmor or similar.

Now, some of these may result in a Java exception when you attempt to change the permission.  But that is up to the OS and the file system drivers.  Java can only throw an exception if the OS *tells* Java that the permission change attempt failed, and it can only report / interpret the reason (the `errno`) returned by the `chmod` syscall.

Comment: but my code does not throw a Java exception at all anytime, and it sometimes works, sometimes does not work, how can your answer explain this?

Comment: Like I said, the operating system may not report the problem to Java. If it doesn't you won't get an exception. If there is no exception, it is not actually possible to tell you what the actual problem (i.e. the "exact issue") is ... without doing a proper examination of the machine on which the problem is occurring. That is not really a Java problem. It is a problem for a skilled system administrator.

Comment: Your clarifications make sence. 
Yeah, this is an env issue, which has been fixed by our devop engineer. Thank you so much!